# How do I view different representations of integers in the Eclipse watch window?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I would like to view binary (or hex) representations of integers in my watch window in Eclipse when debugging. How do I do this?

Answer (score 49):

You can do this from Window->Preferences.

For primitives, browse to Java->Debug->Primitive Display Options

Here there is a checkbox for 'Display Hexadecimal values'. Check this, and you will see both decimal & hexadecimal representations for primitives in the 'value' column under Variables view when debugging.

For objects (Integer, Long, etc), browse to Java->Debug->Detail Formatters

For each type you care about, create a detail formatter that formats the value how you like. For java.lang.Integer, you could use the detail formatter: Integer.toHexString(this)

Make sure your detail formatter is enabled, and you should see the hexadecimal representation in the 'details' area when you select a variable from the Variables view.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for arrays. I'm trying to display an int[] as hex, but changing the primitives doesn't change it and I don't know what class to specify for eclipse to translate.

Comment: It doesn't work for an unexpanded array in the Variables view, but when expanded it should still show the hex values of the array elements. [screenshot](http://i926.photobucket.com/albums/ad105/onelin/java-variables-int-array.png). I can't think of a way you'd specify an array under detail formatters either...

Answer (score 13):

Your best option is probably to open the **Expressions** view (Window -> Show View -> Expressions), right click, choose "Add Watch Expression" and then enter `Integer.toBinaryString(yourInt)` or `Integer.toHexString(yourInt)`, and click ok.